# phpbb poll - Enlarge Images on hover

Tags: php, forum, phpbb, phpbb3, forums

I'm using phpbb forum software.

I have a few images as a set of options in a phpbb poll .  I display the images using the bbcode

```
[img] path to image [/img]
```

What i would like to do is when the user hvers the mouse over this image, it should enlarge

How can i achieve this ? I tried a few things - modifying the css for img in common.css and trying to add some styling to the img bbcode but it doesn't work...

Any help is appreciated.

Also is there a  better way to put images inside a poll?

Answer (score 1):

This does the job, but requires CSS3 support.

```
img.swell:hover {
    transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);}
```

and then

```
<img class="swell" src="image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file which includes styling for the image you can have the main style as something like

```
.poll_image { width: 50px; height: 50px }
```

and then on mouseover

```
.poll_image:hover { width: 100px; height: 100px }
```

That should then double the width & height of the image whilst the mouse is over it, but go back to normal when it moves back out.